# Redirect way except Ajax/Javascript to send the authentication request to avoid CORS error

Tags: java, redirect, cors, saml-2.0, adfs

Issue description:

Assuming I have one web application(Java+Saml2.0) who has a Sign in button to call ADFS(an identity provider) to authenticate.

It's using Javascript(Ajax has same issue) to call one endpoint of ADFS 2016. Since the request if sending from Javascript/Ajax, the browser would throw CORS error. (The ADFS2016 server side doesn't support modifying CORS header/response/origins)

And I heard from someone that one way to avoid the CORS error is to use redirect instead of using Ajax/Javascript to directly call one URL/endpoint.

Can someone give some insights for this situation? How can I modify my code to do such redirect without causing CORS?

PS: I don't want to lower browser security level to bypass CORS and I also don't want to upgrade to ADFS2019 though it supports customizing CORS origins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure if you are trying to achieve some special case by using javascript like this. But normally when authenticating a using using SAML you issue a HTTP redirect from the backend as a response to the user clicking the login button.

To understand it all it is important to first understand the SAML authentication flow as I go through in [this post](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/05/saml-web-profile.html).

1. The user triggers authentication by navigating to a protected page or in this case clicking a button
2. The application, or Service Provider(SP) in SAML speak, builds a SAML authentication request and sends it to the IdP by adding it as a URL parameter and sending a backend HTTP Redirect to the user. The authentication request can also be sent using HTTP POST [explained here](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/post-binding-opensaml-4/)
3. The IdP authenticates the user in the way it sees fit.
4. The IdP send the user back to the SP using HTTP POST together with a SAML Response and SAML Assertion. This contain the result of the authentication as well as any extra information about the user.
5. The SP, you application, interprets the SAML Response and lets the user through to the protected application.
   This redirect contains a encoded SAML authentication request in the URL that is parsed by ADFS to understand where the authentication request is coming from and how authenticates the user.

There are several libraries and frameworks for managing SAML trafic including the sending the messages using redirect or other methods. If you are using Java, Spring has SAML management as a [part of their security framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#saml2). Another library is the PAC4J which provides a [SAML module](https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/saml.html)

While both of these work well for the most general use case of building a SP to integrate with a existing IdP, if you need to do more custom cases or build a IdP on your own OpenSAML can be an alternative.
OpenSAML is a more low level library for handling SAML. [In this write up on my blog](http://%20blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/01/redirect-with-authnrequest.html) I show how to build and send a SAML authentication request using redirect from OpenSAML.

Below is a simplifies example for using OpenSAML. For a full example see the [sample code here](https://github.com/rasmusson/OpenSAML-sample-code/tree/main/getting-started-authnrequest) and [here](https://github.com/rasmusson/OpenSAML-sample-code/tree/main/opensaml-http-redirect)

The authentication request is build using OpenSAML

```
AuthnRequest authnRequest = OpenSAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(AuthnRequest.class);
authnRequest.setIssueInstant(Instant.now());
authnRequest.setDestination(IPD_SSO_DESTINATION);
authnRequest.setProtocolBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_ARTIFACT_BINDING_URI);
authnRequest.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(SP_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE_URL);
authnRequest.setID(RANDOM_ID);
authnRequest.setIssuer(ISSUER);
authnRequest.setNameIDPolicy(NAME_ID_POLICY);
```

Add the message to a message context and set set destination

```
MessageContext context = new MessageContext();
context.setMessage(authnRequest);

SAMLPeerEntityContext peerEntityContext =     context.getSubcontext(SAMLPeerEntityContext.class, true);
SAMLEndpointContext endpointContext =     peerEntityContext.getSubcontext(SAMLEndpointContext.class, true);
endpointContext.setEndpoint(MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ENDPOINT);
```

Send the message using HTTP Redirect

```
HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder encoder = new HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder();
encoder.setMessageContext(context);
encoder.setHttpServletResponse(httpServletResponse);

encoder.initialize();
encoder.encode();
```

For those who want to dig in deeper I have have written a book on working with OpenSAML, *[A Guide to OpenSAML](https://shop.samlsecurity.com/b/41Tw)*, as well as book on SAML as a framework, *[SAML 2.0: Designing secure identity federation](https://shop.samlsecurity.com/b/fGWSH)*.

I also have a ton resources on [my blog](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/)

Comment: I have the similar issue, where I am not trying to do anything special. The problem was I am using a reverse proxy (using express with react). When user try to login, it goes through the reverse proxy to the backend (using Spring SAML2). The backend will try to redirect to the ADFS like you say. However, at this point, the user browser will through the CORS error. Is this because it was re-directed from the backend server to ADFS? How to setup to avoid this?

Comment: oh, just used Windows Server 2019 so that i can set to allow CORS and allow origins. Now to CORS error is resolved. (Cause previously using Windows Server 2016, it does not have this feature)

Comment: Hi Stefan, I really like this direction. May I know more details about "you issue a HTTP redirect from the backend as a response to the user clicking the login button."? Something like a small code snippet? Thx in advance :)

Comment: Well, this is just a backend redirect. I classic java servlets you would do a redirect like this resp.sendRedirect(url); You will how ever need some library in the backed to help you build SAML requests and parse responses. There are several available. Here is a post of mine showing how use OpenSAML build request and redirect. https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/01/redirect-with-authnrequest.html

Comment: Thx a lot for the resources. I think this is the redirect way I'm looking for. @bmw34 And may these resources also work for you.

Comment: @LoLance I added in some more information, links and snippets. Was this what you where looking for in your bounty?

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for. Great thanks!